# cant get cookie Values (NameValueCollection) - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I used belowe code to add cookie  , I add some key, value in cookie ,

```
 public static void AddCookie(this HttpContextBase httpContextBase, string cookieName, NameValueCollection cookieValues, DateTime expires, bool httpOnly = false)
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName)
        {
            Expires = expires,
            //Value = httpContextBase.Server.UrlEncode(value),// For Cookies and Unicode characters
            HttpOnly = httpOnly
        };

        cookie.Values.Add(cookieValues);
        //httpContextBase.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

and fill keys like this :

```
NameValueCollection CookieValues = new NameValueCollection();
                CookieValues.Add("pid", shoppingCartViewModel.ProductId.ToString());
                CookieValues.Add("qty", "1");
                HttpContext.AddCookie(shoppingCartCookiName, CookieValues, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
```

when I want read cookie , Values are null .
I used belowe code to check Cookie Value

```
 public static NameValueCollection GetCookieValues(this HttpContextBase httpContext, string cookieName)
    {
        var cookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookieName];
        if (cookie == null)
            return null; //cookie doesn't exist

        // For Cookies and Unicode characters
        return cookie.Values;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Request.Cookies` not `Response.Cookies` while reading the cookie.

Instead of

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookieName]
```

Use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName]
```

In a web application the request is what comes from the browser and the response is what the server sends back. While reading cookie data from the browser you should use the Request.Cookies. When you are constructing cookies to be sent to the browser you need to add them to Response.Cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("name");
```